# $rootScope not updating using forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach, rootscope

Funny behaviour? My menus object contains menu items which in this moment of code are = true. this snippet is running in a factory.

```
angular.forEach($rootScope.menus, function(menu){
   menu = false;
   console.log(menu); // outputs false
})
console.log($rootScope.menus); //values are still equal to true
```

It would seem that while the value in the loop is being set to false, it is not being applied to the $rootScope, or rather not updating? Does the new value need to be applied?

Kind Regards,

Comment: Why are you binding `menus` to `$rootScope` as opposed to instantiating $scope at the controller level?

Comment: @Haymaker87 ideally this will be a directive in any case. Irrelevant, as the behaviour is at question right now and not the architecture. I am merely curious why the above does what it does.

Comment: Okay, was just curious. I'm not sure that that's good practice or not. Anyways, I second Ryan Jenkin's answer.

Comment: @Haymaker87 The reason for this is a load-screen being loaded during a search, which should close all open menus. This should be handled through a directive detecting outside clicks, probably being best practice. Literally just a quick proof of concept to show the behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forEach has a copy of the array element passed in (passed by value instead of passed by reference). To update the original array use $rootScope.menus[i]:

```
angular.forEach($rootScope.menus, function (menu, i) {
    $rootScope.menus[i] = false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that works and actually makes sense now that I think about it. Also thank you for answering the question while explaining the behaviour.